# docker-compose environment variables scope question: command not behaving the same inside container and out

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am having an issue passing (or perhaps understanding?) environment variables via the "service -> command" vs using them inside the container's CLI.

This is a pseudo docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  service:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
    command: "printenv"
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=some.host
```

If I run the above with `docker-compose up --build`, I get the following output as a result of the `printenv` command for the ENVIRONMENT vars:

```
service_1  | SHLVL=1
service_1  | OLDPWD=/
service_1  | PATH=/command:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
service_1  | PWD=/app/src
```

However, if I remove the `command` key on the service description and go into the container cli and run
`$ printenv`

I get:

```
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
REDIS_HOST=some.host
PWD=/app/src
```

As you can see, there is an inconsistency between the two.

My "real" objective is to use this ENV vars inside Python scripts (which are also not seeing the ENV vars), so getting the actual var value into the `printenv` result is the objective, not really "printing" the value.

EDIT:

As requested, the pseudo-Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM lsiobase/rdesktop-web:alpine AS base
FROM base AS service
CMD printenv
```

I believe this has to do with lsiobase image more than anything else.  If I change the image to something like `FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye AS base` things mostly work, but then I cannot add Libreoffice, which is the root need where everything started.

---

I hope this is clear, thanks for any help.

Best regards,
Rafa.

Comment: Please show your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: The act of running an interactive shell will change the environment; for example, `$HOME` frequently isn't set in a container.  I'd expect the `printenv` form to be more representative of what the container process will actually see (though I do absolutely expect to see `$REDIS_HOST` set).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have added the Dockerfile

Comment: `go into the container cli` How do you "go into the container cli"?

Answer (score 0):

> go into the container cli and run $ printenv

Yes, and when you "go into the container cli", what you are really doing is you are executing a shell, and in that shell you are typing `printenv`, which makes that shell executes a program `printenv` with whatever the shell decides that the environment should be. And that shell decided to add `HOME` variable to the environment of the program. Shell.

Note that there is a difference in startup files between interactive and non-interactive shell. Typically https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html . If you want to source login interactive startup files, source them yourself `command: bash -lc '. ~/.bashrc && printfenv'` or similar.